# Rails: avoiding loops for modal construction, or dynamic modals

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

All across my application I have repeating code for modals and the like, much like this:

```
<% @documents.each do |d| %>
  <div class="modal hide fade" id="deleteModal<%= d.id %>">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
      <h3 id="deleteModal<%= d.id %>Label">Deleting <%= d.title %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Make sure you want to delete <%= d.title %> before doing so.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', d, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is there a design pattern to encourage dynamic code for instances like this? Maybe something jQuery or similar-based? It feels very wasteful to me. Or does it not matter that much?

Comment: You definitely want to dry up your code wherever possible.  Wherever you find yourself repeating code you should be looking to utilize partials, helpers and filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to write a helper method with the TagHelper (if the modal structure never changes).  More specifically by nesting content_tag - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Something like:

modal_helper.rb

```
module ModalHelper

   def delete_modal(d)
      @id = d.id
      @title = d.title

      content_tag(:div, header + body + footer(d), class: "modal hide fade", id: "deleteModal#{@id}")
   end

   def header
      content_tag(:div, content_tag(:button, "x", class: "close", type:"button", data-dismiss:"modal", aria-hidden:"true") + content_tag(:h3, "Deleting #{@title}", id: "deleteModal#{@id}Label"), class: "modal-header")   
   end

   def body
      content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, "Make sure you want to delete #{@title} before doing so."), class: "modal-body")    
   end

   def footer(d)
       content_tag(:div, content_tag(:button, "Cancel", class: "btn", data-dismiss:"modal", aria-hidden:"true") + (link_to 'Delete', d, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger"), class: "modal-footer")
   end
end
```

Then simply:

```
<%= @documents.each {|d| delete_modal(d)} %>
```

You could ofcourse pass any parameters around that you choose if you wanted different information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, that's a nice idea. Cheers!

Comment: Modals made with this code don't actually render, FYI.

Comment: My bad! Working great. My mistake.

Comment: I was going to say may need a little tweaking but content tag returns raw html so if you can hard code it you can generate it this way :)